# How to query from inside BaseX?

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I have imported my Maven config into `BaseX` but found no way to query it.

I want to query for repository of id="thirdparty-releases"

Neither of the following worked:

```
/settings/profiles/profile/repositories/repository[id="thirdparty-releases"]

db:open("settings","settings.xml")/settings/profiles/profile/repositories/repository[id="thirdparty-releases"]
```

My config follows:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>D:\Users\Dims\Design\!Lib\!m2\repository</localRepository>



  <pluginGroups>

  </pluginGroups>
  <proxies>
  </proxies>
  <servers>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>env-dev</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
          <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
          <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>thirdparty-releases</id>
          <name>JBoss Thirdparty Releases</name>
          <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
          <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
          <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: which language & library do you use ?

Comment: It is XQuery 3.0 from BaseX database

Comment: doc("filename.xml")/document/page[id=1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data has a different namespace (see xmlns in the `<settings />` node). You either have to change the namespace in your query or you could also use the wildcard selector for querying, e.g. `/*:settings/*:profiles/...`

Comment: And how to change namespace in query?

Comment: ```declare default element namespace "http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0";```

Comment: No, otherwise it would work, wouldn't it? At least in the simple xpath snippet you posted you don't declare anything, so where should it be known to the XQuery processor? You have to do that in your XQuery code

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by:

> I want to query for repository of id="thirdparty-releases"

Because that seems more like a maven question to me...?

---

BaseX itself, as I'm sure you're aware, is a stand-alone database.  If you only need to query existing data there's no need to even use a `JDK`, although, as `BaseX` is a Java app, you will need a `JVM` -- so maven doesn't really enter the picture.

It has a GUI and is quite easy to get started with.

If you **also** want to run commands from a Java program then you can always look at the github [examples](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/tree/master/basex-examples) or reference the `Javadoc` on [available](http://docs.basex.org/javadoc/org/basex/core/cmd/package-summary.html) commands.

Of course, there are many `BaseX` questions on stackoverflow, over three hundred currently, and for [basex] [java] I see nearly fifty results.  There's an excellent mailing list where the main developer is quite available and helpful, as well as everyone else on the list.

Admittedly, I don't understand your question.  Why would you import your maven config into `BaseX`?

If you're just looking to run `xpath` or `xquery` on a database, my suggestion would be to use the GUI.